# Service worker call happening twice for non cached urls

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Here are my list of requests caching urls and caching strategy

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-mas2';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/css/style.css?bust=20.2.5',
'require.js?bust=20.2.5'
];
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

  var cacheWhitelist = ['my-site-mas2'];

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Cached request  `'require.js?bust=20.2.5'` call happen once and `'publish'` happen twice in network and time for download is twice. How to make only one call for non cached urls

[image]
[image]

Comment: shouldnt you first open your cache with `caches.open`

Comment: i am not caching all assets. only few are being cached. for cached assests the response is coming from cache. but for non cached urls in network tab 2 calls are happening for eg in the screenshot for publish

Answer (score 0):

This is how Chrome DevTools shows requests and is expected.

There is a request for a resource from the client to the Service Worker and a request from the Service Worker to the server. This will always happen unless the service worker has the response cached and does not need to check the server for an update.